# Mysql: All users with no activity in last X days

Tags: mysql, android-activity

Ok, drawing a blank here, and searching not successful.

- User table: id, name, email
- Activity table: id, timestamp, user_id

Many users, some with lots of activity, some long time ago, some none at all. 
I want all user id's where no activity in last 30 days (or indeed, none at all). Any user where some  timestamp exists in last 30 days to be omitted from result.

Bonus question, rewarded with unicorn tears: How would I alter the query to UPDATE matching user rows, say setting column aged=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate 30 days back by using `INTERVAL` with a plus or minus operator: `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY`.

```
SELECT User.id
FROM User
LEFT JOIN Activity ON User.id = Activity.user_ID
GROUP BY User.id
HAVING MAX(Activity.timestamp) < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    OR MAX(Activity.timestamp) IS NULL
```

THE `MAX(Activity.timestamp) IS NULL` should take care of users who have no activity.

Comment: Many thanks. Damn I was getting close with select u.*, a.id, a.timestamp  from user u
left join activity a on u.id = a.user_id
and max(a.timestamp)<date_sub(now(), interval 30 day)
order by u.id

Comment: Ed, That's brilliant - but there's always more (sorry to be so demanding) - have you seen the edit above ?

Comment: Ouch - I'm terrible with the UPDATE / JOIN thing :) The only advice I can offer is to try this: `UPDATE User SET aged = 1 WHERE id IN (` *the entire query above* `)`.

Comment: So am I, hence me asking you ! I was thinking of the same, so we're probably right